# "Down" to Jerusalem?

Tags: geography, kavod, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I have heard many people say "up to Jerusalem", i think as a sign of respect. It also happens to be that it's on a mountain, so you do have to go up.

But is there a problem with saying "down" to/in Jerusalem? Like, from northern Israel, Jerusalem is to the south, commonly known as "down". Perhaps an issue of disrespect?

Comment: Relevant background sources: *Y'sha'ya* [2:2-3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1002.htm#2), *Kiddushin* [69a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=69&format=text)-[b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=69b&format=text), and *Sifrei* (*D'varim*, end of 37, "ארץ ישראל לפי שגבוהה מכל משובחת מכל... בית המקדש שגבוה מכל משובח מכל, וכו").

Comment: It's also noteworthy that most maps that one will find in Seforim do not necessarily put North at the top